# Deleting a specified `Link` from `LinkedList`

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

folks, I'm having trouble with removing a specified `Link` from a `LinkedList`. For example, if I have:

```
"A" --> "B" --> "C"
```

and would like to remove a `Link` `"B"`, so the result would be:

```
"A" --> "C"
```

I'm having troubles with how to get the previous `Link` `"A"` and reference to `"C"`. Can anyone help me out with that? The method is:

```
 public void delete(String data){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            Link current = firstLink;
            Link previous = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                if(current.getData().equals(data)){
                    previous = current.getNext();   
                }
                else{
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Class `Link`

```
package LinkedList;

public class Link{

    private String data;
    private Link next;

    public Link(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public Link getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }
}

class LinkedList{

    private Link firstLink;

    public LinkedList(){
        this.firstLink = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (this.firstLink == null);
    }

    public void insert(String data){
        Link newLink = new Link(data);
        Link newLinkNext = newLink.getNext();
        newLinkNext = firstLink;
        firstLink = newLink;
    }

    public Link deleteFirst(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        else {
            Link deletedOne = this.firstLink;
            Link nextLink = firstLink.getNext();
            firstLink = nextLink;
            return deletedOne;
        }
    }

    public void delete(String data){
    if(isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The list is empty!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        Link current = firstLink;
        Link previous = firstLink;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.getData().equals(data)){
                previous = current.getNext();   
            }
            else{
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even see any attempt to join A to C. You need to know the node before B so you can make the node before B point to the node after B...

Comment: @John3136, that's my question how should I get the Node before `"B"`?

Comment: You have a `while` loop - why not remember the previous value each time through the loop?

Comment: @John3136, I've updated the code. Havent tested yet but will be doing in a sec

Comment: Should be `previous.next = current.getNext()` and not `previous = current.getNext()`. Should probably put a check if `current == firstLink` and deal with that appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample tried to make it similar to your code

```
public class LinkedList {

private Node firstNode = null;

public LinkedList() {
}

public Node getFirstNode() {
    return firstNode;
}

public void setFirstNode(Node firstNode) {
    this.firstNode = firstNode;
}

public void addNode(Node node) {
    if(firstNode == null){
        firstNode = node;
    }else{
        Node walker = firstNode;
        while(walker.getNext() != null)
            walker = walker.getNext();
        walker.setNext(node);
    }
}

public void delete(int value) {
    if (firstNode != null) {
        Node walker = firstNode;
        if (walker.getValue() == value) {
            if(walker.getNext()!=null){
                firstNode = walker.getNext();
            }else{
                setFirstNode(null);
            }
        } else {
            Node previous = walker;
            while (walker.getNext() != null) {
                previous = walker;
                walker = walker.getNext();
                if (walker.getValue() == value) {
                    previous.setNext(walker.getNext());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing to delete");
    }
}

public void listValues (){
    if(firstNode != null){
        Node walker = firstNode;
        while(walker.getNext() != null)
        {
            System.out.println(walker.getValue());
            walker = walker.getNext();

        }
    }
}
```

}

public class Node {

```
private Node next = null;
private int value;

public Node(Node node, int value) {
    this.next = node;
    this.value = value;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node node) {
    this.next = node;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

public class Simulate {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 1));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 2));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 3));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 4));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 123));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 5));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 6));
    list.listValues();


    list.delete(1);
    System.out.println("-----");
    list.listValues();

    list.delete(123);
    System.out.println("-----");
    list.listValues();


    list.addNode(new Node(null, 123));
    list.addNode(new Node(null, 5));

    list.delete(2);
    System.out.println("-----");
    list.listValues();

    list.delete(26);
    System.out.println("-----");
    list.listValues();
}
```

}

### and output: 1 2 3 4 123 5

### 2 3 4 123 5

### 2 3 4 5

### 3 4 5 6 123

3 4 5 6 123

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
prev = null;
current = first;
while not at the end of the list
{
    if (current.data == the object I want) {
        if (prev == null) {
            first = current.next
            break
        }
        prev.next = current.next
        break;
    }
    prev = current
    current = current.next
}
```

Comment: Question, @John3136, why do you have there `prev.next = current.next` ?

Comment: It sets the previous node to point to the next one (so now "current" isn't part of your list). It's in the `if` so you only do it when `current` is the node you want to remove.

Comment: But still it does not work,  @John3136. I've tried the code you gave here

Comment: Then you need to post more details - that pseudo code works - run through it with a pen and paper to confirm - that might help you spot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LLNode
    {
        int data;
        LLNode next;
        public LLNode(int data)
        {
            this.data=data;
        }
    }

public class DeleteNodeFromLinkedList 
{
    /* Link list node */


    /* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
    of a list and an int, push a new node on the front
    of the list. */

    public static void printList(LLNode head)
    {
       LLNode curr = head;
       while(curr != null)
       {
          System.out.print(curr.data+" ");
          curr = curr.next;
       }
    }

    static void deleteNode(LLNode DelNode)
    {
       LLNode temp = DelNode.next;
       DelNode.data = temp.data;
       DelNode.next = temp.next;

    }

    /* Drier program to test above function*/
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        /* Start with the empty list */
        LLNode head = new LLNode(1);
        head.next = new LLNode(4);
        head.next.next = new LLNode(4);
        head.next.next.next = new LLNode(1);
        head.next.next.next.next = new LLNode(12);
        head.next.next.next.next.next = new LLNode(1);


        System.out.println(" Before deleting ");
        printList(head);

        /* I m deleting the head.next
            You can check for more cases */
       deleteNode(head.next);

       System.out.println(" \n After deleting ");
       printList(head);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot operate in lists (add, remove... items) while you iterate on them. You have to use an Iterator

```
 for(Iterator<EmpDedup> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
     EmpDedup data = iter.next();
     if (data.getRecord() == rec1) {
         iter.remove();
     }
  }
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html